# How can I capture only by my program and not by network stack provided by OS?

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, pcap, netfilter

I am working in a project where I need to capture the network packet by my own and process. I can not let existing network stack of operating system to process those packets. I know I can use pcap library to capture the packet. But problem is the same packet, I capture using pcap will be processed by exisitng OS network stack. But I want to process those packet only by my program and not by os.
Please give some light how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

With a prebuilt kernel and interface driver, this would be impossible AFAIK. If you have control over the kernel or the interface device driver, here are some places you can look at.

1. net/core/dev.c, netif_rx() function. This function is called by most of the network device drivers to pass the received packet to the network stack
2. In your interface driver, before calling netif_rx()

You can write a custom device driver, which would implement a queue, which can be read by your user space application.

Answer (score 0):

I have not ever attempted this, but I believe you would be able to get what you need by using a preload library to override all necessary network function (eg. `socket`, `connect`, `listen`, `bind`, `send`, etc). There would be significant functionality to recreate, but it would be possible.

I don't know that this would be the best route to take, but it may be work looking into depending on your requirements.

Comment: But how I can avoid the prebuild library of kernel without modifying kernel?

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood. Are you attempting to capture all incoming packets from a network interface, or all network traffic to and from a specific program?